# Passing Data across multiples views using mvc 3 and EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

maybe this question is seen repeatedly around here but i was not able to find a answers.

my project is about reservations for hotels. I have a class Reservation witch has a Icollection of ChoosenRooms and a class that represents de User making the reservation, and other stuff like dates and other stuff.

The process is this:

In my first view I get the chosen rooms, dates, etc, then i pass that to my second view where i´m going to get the user info, and then i have a third view where i want to show all the gathered information so the user can finally click a button to save the data.

My problem is that i need to pass the reservation object class across all these views. In my testing i see that primitive types pass just fine BUT The iColletion of ChoosenRooms is lost when i post back from the view to the next controller action.

can someone post some example how to, Posting back from a view to a controller, complex types like ChoosenRooms inside another class Reservations, are not lost in the process?

Or maybe explain why this info is lost?

the code:

```
 public class Reserva
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string[] q { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
    public virtual Utilizador utilizador { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quarto")]
    public virtual ICollection<Quartos> ChoosenRooms{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Serviços Adicionais")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReservasItens> itens { get; set; }
```

The view

```
@model SolarDeOura.Models.Reserva
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "AddReservaUser";
        var _reserva = TempData["reserva"] as Reserva;
     }

    <h2>AddReservaUser</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Reserva</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dtEntrada)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dtEntrada)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dtSaida)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dtSaida)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Model.q.Count() Choosen Rooms 
        </div>

        @foreach (var q in Model.ChoosenRooms)
        { 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => q.descricao)
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
```

posting back from here is the Problem. In this view "   @foreach (var q in Model.ChoosenRooms)" has data but posting back the data is lost.

Comment: Is it possible for you to switch to a [single page application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/an-introduction-to-spa/overview/landingpage) (SPA) with MVC4?

Comment: Example is not clear at all. 1st _reserva variable is not used at all. 2nd you are using DisplayFor, not EditorFor. And lastly swapping "modelitem" and "q", I'm not sure if it produce proper element.Id in HTML markup on the page.

And, how controller actions look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of model binder at this point was not very clear to me and some knowledge about this topic is all it takes to solve the question.

In resume:

The view gets a model which is a complex type: class [reserva] has a collection of [ChoosenRooms] which is also a complex type.

The line `@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => q.descricao)` renders the necessary html elements to display the data, but not the necessary html to be posted back to the controller (input element or hidden field ) so the model binder fails.

Also the controller (post) action argument didn't had the property name that matches the field, in this case it needed to be a `String[]` type since its a collection of values.

I would also recommend reading about Display Templates and Editor Templates.